# Export Layout to PDF file type - ArcGIS Pro exported file quality issues

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, layouts, pdf

I'm using the ArcGIS Pro Export Layout function and cannot seem to get a good quality image. I've tried combinations of many of the export options under PDF file type, but what it seems to boil down to is either poor basemap quality or poor layer quality.

Example 1 shows a PDF export with 'Output to image' option selected (300 dpi), other defaults taken. This often results in "tearing" across the image in various spots. Sometimes increasing dpi can assist, but seems to just move the tears elsewhere.

Example 2 shows a PDF export without 'Output to image' checked, other defaults taken. This option seems to provide nicer layer quality overall, but messes up the basemap text. Most all the text comes out in blocky form.

In the past I have exported to PNG or JPEG images to avoid this. Then, keep as those or convert to PDF. However, there must be way Pro can handle exporting in the common PDF format without issues like these, is my thought.

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Comment: Have you fired this off to ESRI? Seems like they would be best placed to answer why the output quality is poor.

Comment: Is this a print or on-screen problem?

Comment: This is an onscreen problem.